# Reading the API documentation

Tags: node.js, rest, http

I am trying to recreate this [create a new card](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-post) API, but based on docs, I'm not sure how should I pass the data required, should it be inside the query parameters (req.params to collect the data), for example
`/1/cards?name=cardName&desc=cardDescription`, or should it be inside the req.body?

Comment: FYI, query parameters arrive in `req.query` in Express, not in `req.params`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc shows plenty of examples for that API.  [One of the examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-post) is even written for nodejs.  It looks pretty clear that the options are query parameters and there is no body data in the request itself.

```
// This code sample uses the 'node-fetch' library:
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/cards?idList=5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(
      `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
    );
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Similarly, the CURL example also makes this fairly clear:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards?idList=5abbe4b7ddc1b351ef961414' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```